# docker container show entry point

Tags: docker, dockerfile

i have question when i run docker command  docker container is up but its shows on Command column below image.
i think it must be show in command column like this 'node /app/server.js'

```
docker container run -e TZ=Asia/Karachi -d -p 9135:9135 myapi:2.4
```

[image]

```
FROM node:10.16.0

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json /app

ENV NODE_ENV=production

RUN npm install

COPY . /app

VOLUME ["/app/logs"]

CMD ["node", "/app/server.js"]

EXPOSE 9135
```

Answer (score 0):

Container main process is `entrypoint` + `command`.

So, what you are getting is the first part of the process (i.e: the entrypoint).

Answer (score 0):

Your expectation is right but the reason is the offical image has [entrypoint](https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/a9c583095d4cf08bbd68f570a1f9a99780820351/8/alpine/docker-entrypoint.sh) and the CMD you are overiding in your Dockerfile is just an argument for the entrypoint that i.e `CMD ["node", "/app/server.js"]`

So, if you change your Dockerfile to

```
FROM node:alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
entrypoint ["node", "/app/app.js"]
```

and then run `docker ps`

The `CMD` will be `"node /app/app.js"`

An example

[image]